# Why the leading zeros in the desired hash pattern?

Tags: mining-theory, hash

Why are leading zeros desired in the block chain hash?  I have searched the internet but cannot find why.

Answer (score 6):

The leading zeros are there to control the difficulty of the problem. More zeros mean a lower space of possible solutions and hence harder problems (more hashes to try before you find one that wins).

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure if it had something to do with sequencing.  It makes sense that it's just to control the difficulty.  It's fascinating.

Comment: Why making it harder? Why it should be difficult to sign a block?